# Facebook PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am running this simple code:

```
<?php
$keyword = 'iPhone';
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?";
$graph_url .= "&type=post";
$graph_url .= "&q=$keyword";
$results = file_get_contents( $graph_url );

$json = json_decode($results);

foreach($json->data as $show ) {
echo '<img src="'.$show->picture.'" alt="some_text"/><br />';
echo $show->from->name . "<br />";
echo $show->message . "<br />";
echo $show->created_time . "<br />";
echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

It is retrieving all facebook posts for the keyword 'iPhone' how come some of the content is empty and the facebook profile pictures don't display on all posts and how would I limit posts. How do I go about fixing this, anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$keyword = 'iPhone';
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?";
$graph_url .= "&type=post";
$graph_url .= "&q=$keyword";
```

//add these lines

```
 $graph_url .= "&fields=from,caption,created_time,picture";
 $graph_url .= "&limit=$number";
```

//

$results = file_get_contents( $graph_url );

```
$json = json_decode($results);

foreach($json->data as $show ) {
echo '<img src="'.$show->picture.'" alt="some_text"/><br />';
echo $show->from->name . "<br />";
echo $show->caption. "<br />";
echo $show->created_time . "<br />";
echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thats limiting the post, thanks! - but it doesn't seem to be displaying posts messages, and some of the profile pictures are QR codes - for example I get:

Jennifer Assmuss

2012-05-12T18:25:38+0000

Comment: actually when we talk about photos there is no messages
insted of dat der are caption see i edited the code

Comment: I think that is closer, but the messages don't appear in what I would see if I searched for public posts using the keyword 'iPhone' e.g. 

Spray Jae Won Kim
brainlab.s3.amazonaws.com
2012-05-12T18:44:29+0000

Comment: messages r not available in pics
first is name of person
den der is a caption
den der is a time it was created

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to only display posts where messages are there?

Comment: add message field and
remove field of picture and caption
den you have to test whether $show->message isset or not n den to echo it